# Entity Framework app.config settings. The default factory and value= with EF6.0

Tags: entity-framework

```
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory 
       type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
         <parameter value="v11.0" />           
      </parameters>
   </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

**EDIT: QUESTION was reworded/reworked.**

**What does `<parameter value="v11.0">` mean ?   Or better Said Why Have just a Db Value?
What about using a full Data Source ? 
And what is LocalDbConnectionFactory implying**

These defaults are hard for me to understand.

Using the Sql default connection factory and parameter used SQL server LocalDbConnectionFactory  did not work.

This did work:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> The configuration section allows you to specify a default connection
>   factory that Code First should use to locate a database to use for a
>   context. The default connection factory is only used when no
>   connection string has been added to the configuration file for a
>   context.

The following configuration will cause Code First to use a LocalDB instance for contexts that don’t have an explicit connection string set.

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v11.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

**Update :** v11.0 is version of the LocalDb.

[more info.](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx)

Comment: Hi Sirwan, i think i understood, when the default will be used.  When Connection names are in or not found in App.config.   I was wondering about what LocalDbConnectionFactory implied. I also a re no clearer as to what the values are supposed to go in the parameter.  I have seen numerous examples, all inconsistent.  Docu seems scarce.  example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.localdbconnectionfactory%28v=vs.103%29.aspx    suggests a localDb can be SQL server.  So im confused why it didnt work.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer, but it wasnt what I was getting at.  Thanks for reply.  I reworded the question to better explain what I dont understand.  The DEFAULT connection info in app.config.  I know when it get used. Not what the values trigger... do and the behaviour. Im looking for docu on the various values to makes sense of it all.

Comment: im still curious about docu on exactly how EF uses the default connection factory... anyway thanks Sirwan

Comment: for using SQL Server 2014 use `<parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />`

Comment: I had copied MVC app files from another project that had user authentication working when I encountered this problem. Having read this answer, I figured out that I had renamed my connection string name from DefaultConnection to something else. I thus simply renamed my connection string in the new app and it worked! I wonder now whether we are never supposed to rename the connections string when using EF...?